# Can't find bug in my threading/atomic values code

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I am using `CodeBlocks` with MinGW compiler and wxWidgets library.

I am writing a program that read some data from the microcontroller, by sending messages (using index and subindex) and getting response messages with said data.

My plan was to send messages one-by-one and waiting for response message using `__atomic int variables__` to check when I get response message.

This is my function for sending a message:

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
void sendSDO(int index, int subindex)
{
    int nSent = 0;

    atomic_index.store(index);
    atomic_subindex.store(subindex);

    canOpenClient->SDORead(index, subindex);
    auto start = Clock::now();
    nSentMessages++;
    nSent++;
    Sleep(10);

    while ((atomic_index.load() != 0) && (atomic_subindex.load() != 0))
    {
        auto t = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - start);
        if(t.count() > 20)
        {
            if (nSent > 5)
            {
                MainFrame->printTxt("[LOG] response not received\n");
                return;
            }
            atomic_index.store(index);
            atomic_subindex.store(subindex);
            canOpenClient->SDORead(index, subindex);
            nSentMessages++;
            nSent++;
            start = Clock::now();
        }
    }
}
```

Pseudocode is set atomic int to index and subindex of what I want value I want to read from microcontroller, then send message to it `SDORead()`, and if no response was received in 20 ms, send the message again, up to 5 times.

For receiving messages, I have a `__separate thread__` with a callback function which is called when I get response message from the controller:

```
void notifyEvent(unsigned char ev_type)
{
    SDO_msg_t msg;
    msg = canOpenClient->Cmd_CustomMessageGet(); //get response message

    if(ev_type == CO_EVENT_SDO_READ)
    {
        if ((msg.index == atomic_index.load()) && (msg.subindex == atomic_subindex.load()))
        {
            //does stuff, like saves message data to set container

            atomic_index.store(0);
            atomic_subindex.store(0);
        }
    }
    if (message data not in container)
        printf("not in container!")
}
```

Here I set the same atomic int values to 0, when the correct response message is received, and save response message data

I also have variables `nSentMessages` and `nReceivedMessages`, which hold the number of messages sent and messages received. I check at the end if these values are the same. Normally, I wouldn't need this (since I wait for every response), I put it there as an extra safety measure.

Now onto the problem:

1) My problem is in callback function `notifyEvent()`, where I presumably save response message data to a container, but I still sometimes get "not in container!" from that if statement and I don't know why. (My container is just normal set `set<EDSobject, cmp> container`, it's not atomic or anything, since I know there won't be reads/writes to it at the same time from different threads.)

2) If you check my function `sendSDO()`,  there is a line `Sleep(10)`. The program works ok with it, but if I remove it, the program returns a different value for `nSentMessages` and `nReceivedMessages` - 576 and 575. This happens every time I run the program and I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure that access to `canOpenClient` is thread safe? (Does the doc. grant this?) Otherwise, I would suspect that the `Sleep(10);` just increases the chance that accesses does "accidentally" not collide.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for your comment. Accesses to what exactly? container? atomic variables? SDORead() sends message to the microcontroller, which returns response message, which I catch in notifyEvent() function.

Comment: Please, note that I know nothing about what you do - I just read your code. ;-) `canOpenClient->SDORead(index, subindex);` calls the member function `SDORead()` of object `canOpenClient`. (I don't know the type - code missing.) Similar for `msg = canOpenClient->Cmd_CustomMessageGet();` which you stated is run in another thread. I (wildly) assumed that both `canOpenClient` are the same and only object. In this case, my "MT alarm bells" ring -> concurrent access to one object from two threads. This is something which must be done thread safe. Either the object has this built in (RTFM)...

Comment: ...or you have to do some (mutex) locking to guard this on your own.

Comment: May be, all my assumptions are non-sense. There is too much code missing in your question to answer this thoroughly. Usually such questions are commented with a request of a [mcve]. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Hey, actually you were write. I was accessing to same objects from different threads, which produced undefined behaviour. I put mutexes in and always locked/unlocked when using shared objects. So far it works great. So thank you for your help!